# Why does not work validation ng-class?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have the following HTML input:

```
 <input type="text" name="artist" maxlength="45"
ng-class="{'error': $scope.formAddSong.artist.$invalid && !$scope.formAddSong.artist.$pristine && $scope.formAddSong.artist.$setUntouched}"
class="form-control" placeholder="Artist"
ng-minlength="minlength"
ng-model="formSong.artist[$index]"
required autofocus>
```

And form with name `name="formAddSong"`.

So, when I touched input and leave this empty, I dont get class `error` on this element.

Comment: Change $setUntouched to $untouched

Comment: I deleted `$setUntouched to $untouched ` and validation works, but afetr submit form and clear form all fields have error class

Comment: Just debug .. add `{{$scope.formAddSong.artist.$invalid}}` after input to check the values.

Comment: When I submit form after I get all fields as empty with class error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one :

```
<input type="text" name="artist" maxlength="45"
                           ng-class="{'error': $scope.formAddSong.artist.$touched && $scope.formAddSong.artist.$error}"
                           class="form-control" placeholder="Artist"
                           ng-minlength="minlength"
                           ng-model="formSong.artist[$index]"
                           required autofocus />
```